# How to import recovered MSN emails

Tags: email

I recently recovered a large number of emails from MSN explorer off a failed hard drive. I'm trying to import them into the MSN local folders on the client's new disk.

I physically put the files in the MSN local folder `C:\Documents and Settings\clientname\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\MSN\db`. The user's other emails were in that folder too, so I'm pretty sure it was the right one. However, MSN explorer does not list those emails in the stored folders. I went through all the menus but I couldn't find any setting to sync MSN local folders. I guess it's supposed to happen automatically but isn't. Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of files are you working with? Is it EML files? Don't you have an option to import e-mails in the MSN Explorer window? Even though, as you say, you moved or copied the email files to that folder where MSN Explorer stores e-mails, it's possible that MSN Explorer doesn't see them because they have not been registered by the program. Why use MSN Explorer in the first place? I thought that product was discontinued by now. What version is it?...

Comment: It's version 10. It's still in use, much to the dismay of technically minded friends of the ever shrinking user base.

Answer (score 1):

There should be two files titled `msn-com.sdf` and `msn-com_JMF.sdf`. You should find them in the database folder you mention above. You can try renaming these two by adding `.old` at the end of the file names. Then try starting MSN Explorer.

For a more complete coverage on how to backup and how to restore e-mails with MSN Explorer you can see the two links below.

[I backed up my e-mail using MSN Explorer and would like to restore it, what should I do?](http://answers.msn.com/solution.aspx?solutionid=952151b9-f06b-4f52-8351-83e844e550b2)

[Email Help Solutions](http://answers.msn.com/solutions.aspx?productid=30)

The MSN Explorer is rarely used these days, so the user base is very small and the support is limited. However, they do have an active forum at [MSN Solution Center](http://answers.msn.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I had a client that lost his MSN password and was unable to get a new one. We ended up creating a new account in MSN Explorer. The db folder contained the .sdf files from the previous account (the one that was locked out) and the new account. I deleted the new .sdf files and renamed the .sdf files from the previous account with the name of the new account. When I re-opened MSN Explorer the old emails and contacts were there.